# use of too at the end of a sentence

Tags: word-order

Can the sentence

> See you next week too

be read as

> I, too, will be seeing you next week

Or, as I think, it could be read as

> see you this week and the next, too.

Comment: Depends on context: If it is a response to "I will see you all of this week" then it means "In addition to this week I will see you next week also". If it is a response to "I will see you next week" then it means they will also see that person next week

Answer (score 1):

> See you next week too

is a grammatically correct and complete sentence, but it is impossible to say definitively what it means without knowing the context. Depending on the situation, it could have either of the meanings that you have suggested.

Another possible interpretation would be if you had just bidden farewell to one friend saying

> see you next week!

Then another friend leaves immediately after and you say

> see you next week, too!

I this case, it would mean

> I will see you next week as well as seeing the other friend next week.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither of the two.

Clearly, *too* is attached with the time referred to in the sentence, i.e., *week* in this case.

This is more like the person has already seen the subject in the current week, and is willing to do the same in the coming week.